# Positional operator targets wrong element of array field in `findOneAndUpdate` update query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a document

```js
{
    "_id": "62ac8190ddb08e6ee5f2c7dd",
    "status": "NEW",
    "vendor": "62ac8171ddb08e6ee5f2c7ca",
    "productsInOrder": [
      {
        "product": "62ac8176ddb08e6ee5f2c7cd",
        "amount": 1
      },
      {
        "product": "62ac8181ddb08e6ee5f2c7d0",
        "amount": 1
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2022-06-17T13:28:48.815Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-06-17T13:39:44.073Z",
    "orderNumber": 82,
    "__v": 2
  }
```

And a query to update second element of `productsInOrder` array in the document

```js
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({
  status: "NEW",
  vendor: "62ac8171ddb08e6ee5f2c7ca",
  "productsInOrder.product": "62ac8181ddb08e6ee5f2c7d0",
  "productsInOrder.amount": {
    $lte: 3
  },
  
},
{
  $inc: {
    "productsInOrder.$.amount": 1
  }
})
```

After executing the update query I expect product with id `"62ac8181ddb08e6ee5f2c7d0"` to be updated, i.e it's amount increased by 1

```js
{
    "_id": "62ac8190ddb08e6ee5f2c7dd",
    "status": "NEW",
    "vendor": "62ac8171ddb08e6ee5f2c7ca",
    "productsInOrder": [
      {
        "product": "62ac8176ddb08e6ee5f2c7cd",
        "amount": 1
      },
      {
        "product": "62ac8181ddb08e6ee5f2c7d0",
        "amount": 2 // increased by 1
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2022-06-17T13:28:48.815Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-06-17T13:39:44.073Z",
    "orderNumber": 82,
    "__v": 2
  }
```

but instead product with id `"62ac8176ddb08e6ee5f2c7cd"` gets updated as seen here https://mongoplayground.net/p/UEU5LCAVjD0

I don't understand why positional operator selects the first element of the array instead of the element specified in find query

How can I update array element of the same `id` that is specified in find query in `"productsInOrder.product"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#multiple-array-matches):

> The positional $ update operator behaves ambiguously when filtering on multiple array fields.
>
> When the server executes an update method, it first runs a query to
> determine which documents you want to update. If the update filters
> documents on multiple array fields, the subsequent call to the
> positional $ update operator doesn't always update the required
> position in the array.

Since your query specify `productsInOrder.product` and `productsInOrder.amount`, it's considered to be filtering on multiple array fields. In your case, you should use [$elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) instead:

```
db.collection.update({
  status: "NEW",
  vendor: "62ac8171ddb08e6ee5f2c7ca",
  productsInOrder: {
    $elemMatch: {
      product: "62ac8181ddb08e6ee5f2c7d0",
      amount: {
        $lte: 3
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $inc: {
    "productsInOrder.$.amount": 1
  }
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fxZ3hPf7Ob2)

Comment: I should start reading docs 